# Issue while deploying the modern site SharePoint Starter Kit v2

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp-provision

I am having issue running the starter kit 2 available [here](https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit)

Below is the error i am getting

[image]

Below are the steps i followed from the article

> ```
> Install-Module -Name "SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline" -RequiredVersion 3.20.2004.0
> ```

> ```
>  Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/  -PnPO365ManagementShell
> ```

> ```
> Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com
> ```

Change to the provisioning folder found in this solution's root and execute the following command

> ```
>  Apply-PnPTenantTemplate -Path .\starterkit.pnp
> ```

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions given [here](https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/issues/312) and [here](https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/issues/274)?

Comment: Yes I have no luck

Comment: Have you or can you try without the .\ in the path?

Comment: Yes i have tried that as well, and lots other things as well

Comment: Do you have MFA on SP activated? If you have, check this link with similar error https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/issues/417

Answer (score 0):

Run PowerShell **as administrator** and use full path in **-Path** for example:
Apply-PnPTenantTemplate -Path C:\temp\starterkit.pnp

Comment: Hi Piotr, i tried it and it is giving the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should not connect to the admin site and not use the -PnPO365ManagementShell attribute, as this is not supported (stated in the documentation) and connecting twice will get you 2 open connections where you can hardly tell which is the actively used one.

According to documentation you should only connect using the following command and then run the Apply-PnPTenantTemplate script.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com
```

Make sure you close PowerShell and reopen it to get rid of previous sessions and best is always to close sessions properly at the end. (Disconnect-PnPOnline)